# Estimate the voltage across each capacitor, in each of the following circuits, after the MOSFET's have turned on

Tags: cmos

I am not sure how to solve this one.
I have the LTSpice simulation but I need help solving it by hand.
Here is the question:

[image]

The simulation from LTSpice is as follows:
NMOS:

- 1pF -> goes to 2.58V
- 10pF -> goes to 2.17V
  PMOS:
- 1pF -> goes to 0.67V
- 10pF -> goes to 0.74V

Here are the simulation images:

[image]

[image]

And the attached text file has the spec for the MOSFET:

```
* Long channel models from CMOS Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation,
* Level=3 models VDD=5V, see CMOSedu.com
*                                                                   
.MODEL N_1u NMOS LEVEL  = 3                  
+ TOX    = 200E-10         NSUB   = 1E17            GAMMA  = 0.5          
+ PHI    = 0.7             VTO    = 0.8             DELTA  = 3.0         
+ UO     = 650             ETA    = 3.0E-6          THETA  = 0.1          
+ KP     = 120E-6          VMAX   = 1E5             KAPPA  = 0.3                
+ RSH    = 0               NFS    = 1E12            TPG    = 1                  
+ XJ     = 500E-9          LD     = 100E-9                 
+ CGDO   = 200E-12         CGSO   = 200E-12         CGBO   = 1E-10              
+ CJ     = 400E-6          PB     = 1               MJ     = 0.5           
+ CJSW   = 300E-12         MJSW   = 0.5                                  
*                                                                               
.MODEL P_1u PMOS LEVEL  = 3                  
+ TOX    = 200E-10         NSUB   = 1E17            GAMMA  = 0.6          
+ PHI    = 0.7             VTO    = -0.9            DELTA  = 0.1          
+ UO     = 250             ETA    = 0               THETA  = 0.1         
+ KP     = 40E-6           VMAX   = 5E4             KAPPA  = 1         
+ RSH    = 0               NFS    = 1E12            TPG    = -1                 
+ XJ     = 500E-9          LD     = 100E-9               
+ CGDO   = 200E-12         CGSO   = 200E-12         CGBO   = 1E-10              
+ CJ     = 400E-6          PB     = 1               MJ     = 0.5                
+ CJSW   = 300E-12         MJSW   = 0.5   
*
*
* Short channel models from CMOS Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation,
* 50nm BSIM4 models VDD=1V, see CMOSedu.com
*
.model  N_50n  nmos  level = 54
+binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 0          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          
+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.4e-009     toxp    = 7e-010       toxm    = 1.4e-009   
+epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 1.2e-008   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.4e-009   
+vth0    = 0.22         k1      = 0.35         k2      = 0.05         k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 2.8          dvt1    = 0.52       
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 2            minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1e-007     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 5.75e-008    lpeb    = 2.3e-010     xj      = 2e-008     
+ngate   = 5e+020       ndep    = 2.8e+018     nsd     = 1e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.0002       cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.15        nfactor = 1.2          eta0    = 0.15         etab    = 0          
+vfb     = -0.55        u0      = 0.032        ua      = 1.6e-010     ub      = 1.1e-017   
+uc      = -3e-011      vsat    = 1.1e+005     a0      = 2            ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = -1e-020      b1      = 0          
+keta    = 0.04         dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.18       
+pdiblc1 = 0.028        pdiblc2 = 0.022        pdiblcb = -0.005       drout   = 0.45       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 1e-007     
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.2          pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 3            rdsw    = 150          rsw     = 150          rdw     = 150        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0          
+prwb    = 6.8e-011     wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          
+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.017        bigc    = 0.0028
+cigc    = 0.002        aigsd   = 0.017        bigsd   = 0.0028       cigsd   = 0.002
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1
+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 6.238e-010   cgdo    = 6.238e-010   cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.495e-10     
+cgsl    = 2.495e-10    ckappas = 0.02         ckappad = 0.02         acde    = 1          
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02       
+kt1     = -0.21        kt1l    = 0.0           kt2     = -0.042        ute     = -1.5
+ua1     = 1e-009       ub1     = -3.5e-019     uc1     = 0             prt     = 0
+at      = 53000
+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          
+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 5e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          
+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0e-008       xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     
+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1
*
.model  P_50n  pmos  level = 54
+binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 0          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          
+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.4e-009     toxp    = 7e-010       toxm    = 1.4e-009   
+epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 1.2e-008   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.4e-009   
+vth0    = -0.22        k1      = 0.39         k2      = 0.05         k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 3.9          dvt1    = 0.635        
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.7          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 0.5e-008     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 5.75e-008    lpeb    = 2.3e-010     xj      = 2e-008     
+ngate   = 5e+020       ndep    = 2.8e+018     nsd     = 1e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000258     cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 6.1e-008     cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.15        nfactor = 2            eta0    = 0.15         etab    = 0          
+vfb     = 0.55         u0      = 0.0095       ua      = 1.6e-009     ub      = 8e-018     
+uc      = 4.6e-013     vsat    = 90000        a0      = 1.2          ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = -1e-020      b1      = 0          
+keta    = -0.047       dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.55       
+pdiblc1 = 0.03         pdiblc2 = 0.0055       pdiblcb = 3.4e-008     drout   = 0.56       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.014        pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 9.58e-007  
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.2          pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 3            rdsw    = 250          rsw     = 160          rdw     = 160        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 3.22e-008  
+prwb    = 6.8e-011     wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          
+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.69         bigc    = 0.0012
+cigc    = 0.0008       aigsd   = 0.0087       bigsd   = 0.0012       cigsd   = 0.0008
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1
+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 7.43e-010    cgdo    = 7.43e-010    cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 1e-014     
+cgsl    = 1e-014       ckappas = 0.5          ckappad = 0.5          acde    = 1          
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02       
+kt1     = -0.19        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = -0.052        ute     = -1.5
+ua1     = -1e-009      ub1     = 2e-018       uc1     = 0             prt     = 0
+at      = 33000
+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          
+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 5e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          
+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0e-008       xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     
+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1
```

Comment: Instead of "jumping right into LTSpice" you should first make an **estimate** by hand. The assignment tells you to do that also! To the estimate simpler, assume that the MOSFETs are ideal switches. The **total charge** doesn't change so calculate what the total charge is before closing the switch. Then the switch closes and the capacitors are shorted. The charge is still the same so you can calculate the voltage. Then **confirm** that number by doing a simulation. The numbers will not be the same, what can cause the difference? (hint: I assumed something).

Comment: I'll give you the hint @Bimpelrekkie left out...the MOSFET structure means that there is effectively a capacitor between the gate and the source and drain.  Your gate threshold voltage will probably come into play as well.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I tried (C1+C2)*Vf = V1*C1+V2*C2 and got 1.19V for NMOS and 3.09 for PMOS. If the effective capacitance given for NMOS is Cox = 3/2 * 25fF/50nm^2 * 0.5nm * 0.05nm = 0.9375fF, and PMOS is the same, how would I use this to find the voltage?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis

Comment: Use the capacitances from your models.  These parameters are affected by mechanisms more complex than just gate area and distance.  http://diyhpl.us/~nmz787/mems/unorganized/SPICE_MOSFET_Model_Intro.pdf

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis How would the equivalent circuit when the switch is closed look like?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I have imported the model from the .txt file. Do you think that will be enough to make it an accurate simulation? Also, how would I take this into consideration when I am solving this by hand?